# Azure function error:"The remote runtime dotnet for function app does not match your local runtime” when publishing a .net 5 function from Visual Code

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When publishing an Azure Function from Visual Code into the "Azure Portal" I get the following error:
"The remote runtime "dotnet" for function app "webhooksdie" does not match your local runtime "dotnet-isolated"."
So how can I publish into the portal with .net 5.0?

Comment: Did you create a function app in the portal where you picked .net 5 as run time, to which you are trying to publish from local ?

Comment: I can't pick up .net 5 on the azure portal. I'm using visual code

Answer (score 2):

I had to manually set the [`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_runtime) setting of the function app to `dotnet-isolated` to make my local runtime match the Azure runtime. Seems to apply to [.NET 5 and 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions).

[image]